# Getting "No tests were found" when running unittest

Tags: python, pycharm

If I click "Run 'Unittest for ..'" in PyCharm it prints:

```
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest /home/sfalk/workspace/git/m-search/python/tests/cluster/pipeline/preprocessing.py in /home/sfalk/workspace/git/m-search/python/tests/cluster/pipeline
```

and reports

> No tests were found.

However, if I copy this *exact* line which PyCharm claims to run, namely

```
python -m unittest /home/sfalk/workspace/git/m-search/python/tests/cluster/pipeline/preprocessing.py
```

then I get my expected output.

```
$ python -m unittest /home/sfalk/workspace/git/m-search/python/tests/cluster/pipeline/preprocessing.py
..
+---+------------+
| _1|          _2|
+---+------------+
|  1|Hello World!|
+---+------------+

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 4.998s

OK
```

The run configuration says:

> **Script path:** `/home/sfalk/workspace/git/m-search/python/tests/cluster/pipeline/preprocessing.py`
>
> **Working directory:** `/home/sfalk/workspace/git/m-search/python/tests/cluster/pipeline`

I don't get this ..

---

It should not matter imho but here's the code of the unit test:

```
import unittest

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext


class TestPreprocessingText(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_preprocessingText(self):

        conf = SparkConf()
        conf.setMaster('local')
        conf.setAppName('MyApp')
        sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

        sql = SQLContext(sc)

        df = sql.createDataFrame(
            [
                (1, 'Hello World!')
            ]
        )

        df.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Did you create a Python run config or a Python Test run config?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, PyCharm creates that. See *Script Path* and *Working directory*. That's from the config and that's what PyCharm uses in order to generate that command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming your test filename following this convention:

```
app_folder/
    appname.py
    test_appname.py
```

As shown above, the app you are trying to test and the test file are in the same directory following that naming convention.

Comment: Super weird. I can't believe PyCharm lies to me like that. If it was executing the command that it said it would it should have worked, shouldn't it. Anyway - this actually solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanFalk Welcome. This is the most popular convention. Another contender is appname_test.py.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.